# boost zlib filter doesn't works in windows

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, boost-iostreams

I have written a code to read a .z compressed file directly.
It works fine in linux and mac os. But it doesn't work as expected in windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>
// cl /EHsc uncompress.cpp

std::vector<char> & readline(std::istream & stream, std::vector<char> & container) {
    char c;
    container.clear();
    while (stream && stream.get(c)) {
        container.push_back(c);
        if (c == '\n') break;
    }
    return container;
}

int main () {
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream cinn(std::cin);
    in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(cinn);

    std::vector<char> line;
    while (readline(in, line).size() != 0) {
        std::string str(line.begin(), line.end());
        std::cout << "--" << str ;
    }
}
```

while running it as `./a.out < compressed.z` on linux or mac it works fine

while running it from windows `uncompressed.exe < compressed.z` it doesn't show the content of the file.

Why is this behaving so ?

Comment: What character encoding is the uncompressed file?

Comment: Line ending translation?

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` is not opened in binary mode, so it is doing end-of-line conversions on Windows, by default corrupting all input files. There are two solutions:

1. Never, ever use Windows, or try to write applications for it.
2. Use `_setmode( _fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY )` to convert `stdin` to binary mode.